# HOW TO DO Socket Multiple Clients

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

this is a part from a code that making GUI for process list. I'm trying to do a Socket Multiple Clients but it is'nt working. Can some one help me with this?

```
import socket, pickle 
import threading 
import select


BUF_SIZE = 8192


class Network(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.frame = frame
        self.server_sock = socket.socket()

    def run(self, client_sock=None):
        self.server_sock.bind(('', 1729))
        self.server_sock.listen(5)
        self.open_client_sockets = []
        while True:
            self.rlist, self.wlist, self.xlist = select.select([self.server_sock] + self.open_client_sockets, [], [])
            if self.currect_sock is self.server_sock:
                client_sock, client_address = self.server_sock.accept()
                self.open_client_sockets.append(self.new_sock)
                data = client_sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
                processes_list = pickle.loads(data)
                for process_details in processes_list:
                    self.frame.add_line(process_details)
            else:
                data = self.client_sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
                processes_list = pickle.loads(data)
                for process_details in processes_list:
                    self.frame.add_line(process_details)

        client_sock.close()
        self.server_sock.close()
        self.server_sock.close()
```

Comment: No way to help with this. What's not working? What do you expect? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: this is part of a code that makes connection betweein server to several num of clients. this connection between the server to client doesn't work and i don't know how to do this connection (it is in class so i need to do attr)

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you. You haven't given enough information about what you're trying to do. And the code you have provided is fragmentary and incoherent so nobody can even intuit what you're attempting.

Comment: I have posted another post that might be more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691395/how-to-multiplie-clients