# How to multiplie clients

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

This is a part from a code that make connection between server to client. i want to multiplie the client. appriciate help.

```
import socket, pickle import threading

BUF_SIZE = 8192

class   Network(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,frame):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.frame = frame
        self.server_sock= socket.socket()

    def  run(self):
        self.server_sock.bind(('',1729))
        self.server_sock.listen(1)
        client_sock, client_address = self.server_sock.accept()
        data = client_sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
        processes_list = pickle.loads(data)
        for process_details in processes_list:
            self.frame.add_line(process_details)

        client_sock.close()
        self.server_sock.close()
        self.server_sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The common practice is to start a new thread or process for each connected client like (I do not know Python so I will explain it in some pseudocode):

```
create server socket;
listen on specific address;

while (true)
{
     accept client;
     start a new thread for client;
}

close server socket;
```

In new thread you will process every new client connection, need only client socket to pass to the new thead.

```
new thread function (client socket)
{
     read (client socket);
     write (client socket);
     close (client socket);
}
```

I also recomend you to increase listen backlog queue to 2-5 connections.

Comment: according to the blog post, I don't think it's a good idea to increase the number of backlog queue, http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/using-socket-as-server-listening-socket.html